# Run php in a bash script: error "Could not open input file"

Tags: php, bash

I made a simple script like:

```
#!/bin/bash
php /var/www/mysite/script1.php
php /var/www/mysite/script2.php
```

When I run it as root like this:

```
bash update.sh
```

I get following errors:

```
Could not open input file: /var/www/mysite/script1.php
Could not open input file: /var/www/mysite/script2.php
```

What is wrong ? I tried with permissions 777 on my php files and all folders to access it. When I do directly php /var/www/mysite/script1.php in my command line it works fine.

Comment: try to use: `sudo bash update.sh` lets see what will happen.

Comment: Are you executing the bash script the same way as manually running the `php` command?  If you're running one of them through a web service or something the paths might be different.

Comment: wouldn't it be a carriage return end line problem? Can you do the following: `dos2unix update.sh > newbatchfile` and try the new one? (compare file sizes, if the newbatchfile is smaller: bingo)

Comment: Thanks @Jean-FrançoisFabre it works now !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a batch file passes through some windows-compliant editors or other mishaps, it may happen that carriage return chars are appended to the end of the line (just before linefeed)

so the all the lines for instance this one:

```
php /var/www/mysite/script1.php
```

contains an invisible `\r` char which is interpreted as part of the argument py `php` => file `/var/www/mysite/script1.php<invisible char>` not found.

Do the following:

```
dos2unix update.sh > newbatchfile.sh
```

or

```
tr -d "\015" < update.sh > newbatchfile.sh
```

(compare file sizes, if the newbatchfile is smaller, problem was CR chars and is fixed)