# Sendmail Pipe to PHP: Could not open input file

Tags: php, pipe, sendmail, file-permissions, user-permissions

I've installed sendmail and want to pipe incoming emails to php.

Every time I send an email to my server I am getting an email back with an error message:

> could not open input file: /root/fw/catcher.php 554 5.3.0 unknown
>   mailer error 1

I think something with the permissions of `catcher.php` is wrong but I couldn't figure it out by myself.

Sendmail is installed and I have added an alias:

```
root: "|/usr/bin/php /root/fw/catcher.php"
```

Permissions (after `chmod 777`; I tried `chmod 777` and `chmod 755` but both won't work):

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jul 20 14:27 fw
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   45 Jul 20 14:27 catcher.php
```

catcher.php (converted line endings to Unix style):

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php echo 'Test'; exit(0); ?>
```

Executing my php file over cli works fine. All of these commands work:

```
/usr/bin/php /root/fw/catcher.php
/usr/bin/php7.3 /root/fw/catcher.php
php /root/fw/catcher.php
php7.3 /root/fw/catcher.php
```

I think there is a problem with the permissions of sendmail.

Comment: First i would suggest you use a shell script and pass the php file name in that. See this https://serverfault.com/questions/261191/how-to-run-a-script-when-a-mail-arrives-in-mail-server-debian and http://musicalgeometry.com/p/1473

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: What is reported in the log file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error "***could not open input file***" means that the file cannot be read for some reason.

Please follow these steps to check:

1. > converted line endings to Unix style

I do not know how you check this, but you could try to redo this using [dos2unix, as described in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39649685/4448410)

```
dos2unix catcher.php > newcatcher.php
```

and then compare file sizes.

2. it could be that **BOM breaks the script**, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38038099/4448410), the shebang line **"#!/usr/bin/php"** tells the system which interpreter needs to be run when invoking such a script.

> If the script is encoded in UTF-8, one may be tempted to include a BOM at the beginning. But actually the "#!" characters are not just characters. They are in fact a magic number that happens to be composed out of two ASCII characters. If you put something (like a BOM) before those characters, then the file will look like it had a different magic number and that can lead to problems.

The script will run **over cli** because you specifically tell it which intepreter to use: **php** or **php7.3**:

```
php /root/fw/catcher.php
php7.3 /root/fw/catcher.php
```

To remove **BOM** from the start of the file, try [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381230/how-can-i-remove-the-bom-from-a-utf-8-file):

```
dos2unix catcher.php
```

Try to run **/root/fw/catcher.php**, as a shell script without using php or php7.3 executable. From terminal, run:

```
./root/fw/catcher.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked whether SELinux is enabled and enforcing? You can see this with the `getenforce` command.

If this returns `Enforcing`, you can fix this in a few ways. You can either disable SELinux enforcement with `setenforce Permissive`, or create a policy that allows Apache to run sendmail.

To create a policy like this, the easiest way is to use the `audit2allow` tool, which is part of the `policycoreutils-python` - so install that if `audit2allow` isn't available. Then, check `/var/log/audit.log` to see if there are errors about sendmail not being able to run. These error lines can be piped to `audit2allow` to create a policy file that can be enabled with `semodule -i <module.pp>`.